# Why is my for loop overwriting my previous values in the dictionary? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, urllib

I am creating a scraper for msn money. I obtain the values off of the site and run them through a couple for loops to sort them by year. When my for loops finish all the values are those in the 2018 data set. What's wrong with my code?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

values = {}
values_by_year = {}
counter = 2013
dict_index = 0
temp = ''

url = "https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/financials/nas-googl/fi-a1u3rw?symbol=GOOGL&form=PRFIHQ"
tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

for section in tree.xpath('//*[@id="table-content-area"]'):
    for i in range(2, 32):
        for x in     section.xpath('./div/div/div[1]/div/ul[%s]/li[1]/p/text()'
% (i)):
                if i == 6:
                    values[i] = 0
                else:
                    values[x] = 0

for x in range(2015, 2019):
    values_by_year[x] = values


for section in tree.xpath('//*[@id="table-content-area"]'):
    for i in range(2, 32):
        for y in range(1, 6):
            for value in section.xpath(
                    './div/div/div[1]/div/ul[%s]/li[%s]/p/text()' %     (i,y)):

                if y == 1:
                    temp = value
                else:
                    print("value is ", counter+y, "y is ", y)
                    values_by_year[counter+y][temp] = value



print(values_by_year[2016])
print("\n------\n")
print(values_by_year[2017])
```

I receive no error messages. My expected result is for the program to output a dictionary names values_by_year where it contains 4 keys to every year. Each year contains a dictionary of the values corresponding to the year. For example "Period End Date" for 2015 would be 12/31/2015 and for the year 2016 it would be 12/31/2016.

Comment: Hi, 
You should search the web on how to debug code. Try to print what the code is doing to get some insights.

Comment: Ive put print statements everywhere to see what my code is doing and it seems to be doing the right thing but i end up with one dictionary overwritting the values in the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem in your code is this:

```
for x in range(2015, 2019):
    values_by_year[x] = values
```

That sets the keys 2015 through 2018 to refer to the same `dict` of `values`, not copies. So when you do:

```
values_by_year[counter+y][temp] = value
```

you're not just modifying a `dict` associated with `counter+y`, but the one associated with *all* the keys you initialized.

The minimalist fix is to change:

```
for x in range(2015, 2019):
    values_by_year[x] = values
```

to:

```
for x in range(2015, 2019):
    values_by_year[x] = values.copy()
```

so you get your defaults initialized as expected, but insert (shallow) copies of the default `dict` (which, since the values in it are `int`s, is enough).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are after this or not.however using `Beautifulsoup` you can do this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
data=requests.get('https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/financials/nas-googl/fi-a1u3rw?symbol=GOOGL&form=PRFIHQ',headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
dict_data={}
table=soup.select_one('div.table-rows')
cols=table.select('.column-heading .truncated-string')
for col in cols[1:]:
    year=col.text
    periodenddate=col.parent.find_next('div',class_='table-data-rows').find('p',title=re.compile(year)).text
    dict_data[year]=periodenddate

print(dict_data)
```

### Output printed on console:

```
{'2015': '12/31/2015', '2018': '12/31/2018', '2016': '12/31/2016', '2017': '12/31/2017'}
```

Comment: Im trying to organize all of the data into nested dictionaries by year. For example {2015: {start:2015, end:2016, etc}}. I end up having all the values inside of each dictionary be overwritten by the values in the 2018 dataset. All the dictionaries end up having the same values as those in the 2018 dict. For example {2015:{{'Period End Date': '12/31/2018', 'Stmt Source': 'Annual'}, 2016:{{'Period End Date': '12/31/2018', 'Stmt Source': 'Annual'}, 2017:{{'Period End Date': '12/31/2018', 'Stmt Source': 'Annual'}, 2018:{{'Period End Date': '12/31/2018', 'Stmt Source': 'Annual'}}.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using dictionaries and css nth-of-type pseudo class. BS4 4.7.1

`row_dict` is a dictionary initialised with all its keys pulled from all the row column 1 values i.e. `Period End Date , Stmt Source` etc.

```
row_dict = dict.fromkeys([h.text.strip().replace('▶\n▼\n','') for h in table.select('.first-column')][1:])
```

It is looped via enumerate so as to leverage the counter to pass to nth-of-type to select the appropriate row associated with that key

```
for index, header in enumerate(row_dict, 2):
    row = [item.text.strip() for item in table.select('[class^=level]:nth-of-type(' + str(index) + ') .financials-columns')]
```

So, for example:

```
row_dict['Period End Date']
```

will be

```
['12/31/2015', '12/31/2016', '12/31/2017', '12/31/2018']
```

I generate the top level dictionary, `income_statement`, with keys of each year:

```
income_statement = dict.fromkeys([h.text for h in table.select('.column-heading')][1:])
```

I then loop those years generating an inner dictionary associated with each key

```
for i,year in enumerate(income_statement):
    income_statement[year] = dict()
```

I then populate each inner dict by adding to it the keys of row_dict i.e. all the column 1 values. Using enumerate I can then populate the top level dictionary inner year dictionary appropriate value by key

```
for k,v in row_dict.items():
         income_statement[year][k] = row_dict[k][i]
```

---

**Py**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/financials/nas-googl/fi-a1u3rw?symbol=GOOGL&form=PRFIHQ')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('#financials-partial-view')
income_statement = dict.fromkeys([h.text for h in table.select('.column-heading')][1:])
row_dict = dict.fromkeys([h.text.strip().replace('▶\n▼\n','') for h in table.select('.first-column')][1:]) 

for index, header in enumerate(row_dict, 2):
    row = [item.text.strip() for item in table.select('[class^=level]:nth-of-type(' + str(index) + ') .financials-columns')]
    row_dict[header] = row

for i,year in enumerate(income_statement):
    income_statement[year] = dict()
    for k,v in row_dict.items():
         income_statement[year][k] = row_dict[k][i]

print(income_statement)
```

---

**Example of income_statement structure and content:**

[image]